# How to save answers from a calculation into a cell array

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I am trying to compute a value using two initial variables however the answer at the end is getting overwritten and only outputting the final value. I have tried using two nested for loops for the variables however this produces a similar response.

```
% inc = [0:1:360];
% axis = [0:416.6*10^3:15*10^7];
e = [];
Re = 3390*10^3;
om = 270;`
J2 = 1.95545*10^3;
J3 = 3.14498*10^-5;
J4 = -1.53774*10^-5;
J22 = 6.30692*10^-5;

for inc = 0:1:360
    for a = 0:416.6*10^3:15*10^7
        E1 = ((6-169/2*sin(inc).^2+365/48*sin(inc).^4)
        E2 = 35*J4/18*(J2)^2*(12/7-93*sin(inc).^2+21/4*sin(inc).^4);
        E = E1-E2;

        e1 = (J3*Re/2*J2*axis).*sin(inc).*sin(270);
        e2 = (1-(3*E*J2*Re^2/axis.^2)*(5.*(sin(inc).^2)-4));
        e = -(e1/e2);
    end
end
```

I am trying to make the end e value a cell so that I can plot it against the variables inc and axis.

In addition, in case my syntax for my formulas are wrong here are the formulas I am trying to automate.

[image]

where

[image]

Thank you for any help or advice on how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vectorize the code and get the solution without loops. As @schnobi1 said, you should pay more attention to implementation with the divisions and multiplications of numerators and denominators.

```
Re = 3390*10^3;
om = 270;
J2 = 1.95545*10^3;
J3 = 3.14498*10^-5;
J4 = -1.53774*10^-5;
J22 = 6.30692*10^-5;
inc = 0:360;
a = 0:416.6*10^3:15*10^7;
E1 = (6-169/2*sin(inc).^2+395/48*sin(inc).^4);    % 1 x 361 vector
E2 = 35*J4/18*(J2)^2*(12/7-93*sin(inc).^2+21/4*sin(inc).^4);    % 1 x 361 vector
E = E1-E2;                                       % 1 x 361 vector
e1 = [sin(270)*(J3*Re./(2*J2*a))].'*sin(inc);    % vector multiplication, this is now 361 x 361 matrix
e2 = 1-([3*J2*Re^2./a.^2].'*(E./(5*(sin(inc).^2)-4)));   % vector multiplication, this is now 361 x 361 matrix

e = -(e1./e2);
```

The result is 361 x 361 matrix, where rows is according to values of `a`, and columns is according to values of `inc`. 
For example, for `a` in the 4th place and `inc` in the 12nd place you will get:

```
a(4)=

     1249800

inc(12)=

    11

e(4,12)=

  -8.9796e-18
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I was trying to run your code to see my error and I am getting an error that "Error using  ./  Matrix dimensions must agree." in line 15. Is this because of a differing Matlab version?

Comment: Not supposed to. Do `clear all`, then try to run it again. What are the sizes of `e1` and `e2`?

Comment: e1 is a 361x361 matrix however it is unable to compute e2 due to this error using ./

Comment: This is strange. The error is in the line of `e2= ... `? What is the size of `E`?

Answer (score 0):

You are having some errors in your implementation. Please look again carefully at all your terms (like the 395/48 is by you a 365/48). Also the brackets are sometimes set incorrect. I hope I found all of these problems, but please double check it again.

Than you are using the predefined variable "axis". It's used for plots and is defined as [0 1 0 1]. That was the reason why your code wasn't working.
So please try this one.

```
%% Clearing
clc; clear all; close all

%% Variables
e = [];
Re = 3390*10^3;
om = 270;
J2 = 1.95545*10^3;
J3 = 3.14498*10^-5;
J4 = -1.53774*10^-5;
J22 = 6.30692*10^-5;

inc=1
a = 1

%% Calculate e
for inc = 0:1:360
    for a = 0:416.6*10^3:15*10^7
        E1 = 6-(169/12)*sin(inc).^2 + 395/48*sin(inc).^4;
        E2 = 35*J4/(18*J2^2)*(12/7-(93/15*sin(inc).^2+21/4*sin(inc).^4));
        E = E1-E2;

        e1 = (J3*Re)/(2*J2*a) * sin(inc)*sin(270);
        e2 = 1-((3*J2*Re^2*E)/(a^2*(5*sin(inc)^2-4)));
        e = [e, -(e1/e2)];
    end
end
```

To store your e into a matrix, you can simply use `e = [e, -(e1/e2)];`. But please notice, this is not a "nice way". Because in every run, e gets copied and that makes it slow. It is much nicer and faster to allocate e from beginning with zeros and write later the values in it.

Answer (score 0):

U can use direct indexing on all vector point u want to update. Example on your loop use e1(Inc)= your calculation;
e2(Inc)= your calculation;
e(Inc)=-(e1(Inc)/e2(Inc)); however it will be slow but you can your expectations